# Display view content in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, foreign-keys

In my SQL Server when I create a view with 3 tables that have foreign keys to each other, this view does not show my tables contents. I try that with different tables and it does not show content when the tables are more than 2!

How can I fix that?

[My SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N147.jpg)

Comment: May be the third table does not have data. Show the view code and data's present in each table and your expected output

Comment: 3 tables have content, in this picture you can see them, (the userID and userProduct are foreign key) [link](http://s8.picofile.com/file/8275394218/sql_2.JPG)

Comment: What do you get if you run *just* the `SELECT` statement that makes up the view? Do you get any results??

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` if data is shown. It means that a table does not contain any related data with the others